# ¿Cómo validar cuando una lista esta vacia o regresa null en Java?

Tags: java, lista, spring-boot, arraylist, microservices

Tengo el siguiente servicio que consulta a una bd y obtiene una lista de información a traves de dos parametros de entrada, fecha de inicio y fecha fin , quiero agregar la validacion de cuando no haya datos con ese rango de fechas, lanzar ahi una excepcion de no hay datos , como le agregaria esa condicion a mi codigo que ya tengo, seria en la capa del servicio?

cual seria la mejor forma de agregarselo?

Mi Controller quedo de la siguiente forma:

```html
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    public class ConsultarValoresController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  

        @GetMapping()
        public ResponseEntity<?> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, 
        @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception{
            ResponseEntity<?> listaValores = null;
        try {
            listaValores = consultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }
        return listaValores;
    }
```

y el servicio lo deje asi:

```html
@Service
    public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
        
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity<?>consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) {
        
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<ValoresDTO> listaValores = new ArrayList<ValoresDTO>();
        try {
            listaValores = consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
            if(listaValores.isEmpty() || listaValores == null) {
                LOGGER.error("No hay datos con esas fechas ");
                response.put("success", false);
                
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            response.put("success", false);
            response.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, null, HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT);
        }
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("data", listaValores);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, null, HttpStatus.SC_OK);
       
    }
```

```html
 public interface ConsultarValoresRepository  extends JpaRepository<ValoresDto, Integer>{                
        @Query(value="select * from TABLE_VALORES t where t.fechaRegistro between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery =true)
        List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresBd(Integer fechInicio, Integer fechaFin);
    }
```

Ahora de lado de  Angular tenia lo siguiente en mi component.ts, mandaba a llamar al metodo que consulta e invoca al back

```html
consultarDatos() {
    if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe(data=>{
          this.modelConsultarValores=data;
        })
      

    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
      })
    }
  }
```

y en el service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ValoresDto} from '../Models/ValoresDTO';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultarValoresService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultarValores';

  
  consultarValores(fechaInicio:any, fechaFin:any){
    return this.http.get<ValoresDTO[]>(this.Url+ `?fechaInicio=${fechaInicio}&fechaFin=${fechaFin}`);
  }
}
```

pero como modifique el back de que ya no regresa una lista como tal me manda error, como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Está bien que te falten `;`?

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de retornar un `List` puedes retornar un `HashMap`, un mapa formado por clave-valor.

Para retornar el `HashMap`, el controller en lugar de retornar un tipo especifico puedes cambiarlo a `ResponseEntity<?>` esto para devolver success o error en el mismo metodo, la notación `< ? >` se usa cuando se desconoce la clase a modelar

En el ejemplo uso la variable `response` para setear el mapa de respuesta , en caso de error podrías setear con el metodo [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) la  clave `error`

Por el contrario puedes retornar la lista de datos en otra clave, en el ejemplo uso la clave `data`, pero no importa como definas esas claves solo que con estas mismas tendrás que recuperar estos datos en el front

```
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    public class ConsultarValoresController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  

        @GetMapping()
        public ResponseEntity<?> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, 
        @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception{
            
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

            List<ValoresDTO> listaValores = new ArrayList<ValoresDTO>();
        try {
            listaValores = consultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            // se añade la clave error con el valor del error del catch y
            // la bandera succes en false 
            // posteriormente se retorna un codigo de error 409 indicando que 
            //hubo un conflicto
             response.put("success", false);
            response.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response,  HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        // en caso de que la peticion sea correcta se retorna un codigo 200 
        // que indica que la peticion se realizo correctamente
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("data", listaValores);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Por cierto esta lógica quedaría mejor en el `@Service`, en el controller es mejor solo retornar el método de service

**Edit**:
Para recuperar esos datos en front-end, no he utilizado la funcion suscribe, pero con then seria algo como:

```
consultarDatos() {
    if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).then(data=>{
          this.modelConsultarValores=data;
        }, e => e{
           console.log(e.error) // e sera el objeto de respuesta en 
                               //caso de conflicto
        })
      

    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: y aqui en donde caeria si la lista regresa null o vacia, es decir que no se encuentren datos con ese rango de fechas?

Comment: eso seria dentro del try, tu variable listaValores es de tipo List entonces puedes acceder a su metodo size que te retorna el tamaño de datos que tiene, en el try valida si el size es 0 con un if y si se cumple retorna un mensaje o advertencia que te diga que no hay datos en ese rango, asi puedes ir haciendo validaciones, incluso retornar una lista de mensajes

Comment: edito mi pregunta de como quedaria el backend, es correcto?, agrego la logica que tenia en mi service Angular pero como ya se modifico el back ya me manda un error

Comment: Ahora lo que no se es como validar en mi front las respuestas del back, que si la lista esta nula mandar en angular el msj de que no hay datos, o que si fallo la bd de igual forma mostrarlo en pantalla

Comment: edite mi respuesta, recupera las adevertencias desde el back con sus claves, en el ejemplo use la clave error, de ese modo puedes agregar tu sweet alert con el mensaje del objeto de respuesta

Comment: me manda error en el then, me dice Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<ValoresDto[]>'., y asi como yo lo tenia antes de este cambio, al momento de hacer una prueba manda el error ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.