# Duda con expresión lambda a la hora de hacer un save en repositorio Java

Tags: java, jpa, lambda, optional

estoy intentando crear una entidad y quiero retornar el modelo de esta misma en el metodo pero la verdad no se como hacerlo, tengo esto pero me salta error porque me dice que *Bad return type in lambda expression: BankModel cannot be converted to Bank* y le estoy pasando un mapeador que hice con mapstruct aqui les dejo el fragmento de codigo, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

```
@Override
public BankModel saveBank(BankRequest bankRequest) {
    return bankRepository.findByBankName(bankRequest.getBankName().toUpperCase())
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Bank bank = new Bank();
                bank.setBankName(bankRequest.getBankName().toUpperCase());
                bank.setStatus(true);
                bankRepository.save(bank);
                return bankMapper.toBankModel(bank);
            });
}
```

Clase BankRepository y metodo findByBankName:

```
@Repository
public interface BankRepository extends JpaRepository<Bank, Long> {
    Optional<Bank> findByBankName(String bankName);
}
```

Clase BankMapper y metodo toBankModel:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface BankMapper {
    Bank toBank(BankModel bankModel);

    BankModel toBankModel(Bank bank);
}
```

Comment: Explicate mejor, pon algo más de información

Comment: Tengo un método para guardar un banco, este método quiero trabajarlo con programación funcional y quiero antes de crear, verificar si el banco ya existe por nombre, el método lo traigo de la interfaz al servicio entonces con el método de buscar por nombre quiero validar si existe o no y si no existe proceder a crear el nuevo, pero me sale error por que no me esta cogiendo el mapeo de entidad a modelo.

Comment: el metodo findByBankName de que tipo te retorna?, porque si retorna una entidad de tipo bank, es ahi el error, ya que debes retornar un tipo BankModel, me refiero al primer caso, es decir en caso de que la entidad ya exista

Comment: retorna un Optional de tipo bank, pero con el bankMapper hago la conversión de entidad a modelo.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando el metodo findByBankName del bankRepository y el metodo toBankModel de bankMapper, para asi poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Listo ya los añadi

Comment: El problema es cuando la entidad si existe, porque directamente se retorna la entidad de tipo bank encontrada, antes de eso deberías hacer lo mismo que cuando no la encuentra, hay que hacer la conversión a bankModel

Comment: pero es que cuando la encuentre quiero retornar un mensaje diciendo "bank already exist"

Comment: En ese caso no deberias retornar un BankModel, prodrias retornar un [ResponseEntity](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity) en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/468875/c%C3%B3mo-validar-cuando-una-lista-esta-vacia-o-regresa-null-en-java/468891) respondi algo similar

Comment: el response entity los manejo en la capa de controladores, es que se como hacerlo sin expresiones lambdas, es para empezar a trabajar con programacion funcional y entonces al momento de trabajar con el else por decirlo asi de la consulta no se como ponerlo en expresiones lambda